# How do I add an Angular 2 attribute directive to a downgradeComponent in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have the following...

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        SearchComponent,
        ExpandableSearchDirective,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        SearchComponent,
    ],
})
```

Where ExpandableSearchDirective is an attribute directive. How do I add this to the search component if the tag is consumed by AngularJS (Angular 1).

I tried `<px-search ... jg-expandable-search>` with nothing else and I didn't see an error, I also didn't see the directive. I have

```
angular.module('jg')
    .directive('jgSearch', downgradeComponent({
        component: SearchComponent,
    }));
```

For the search but I don't have anything for the expand directive.

Is there something I need to add to `angular` global var or something?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Let me make it simpler for you, a plunker that allows me to use an angular 2 attribute directive in angular 1 code would get the star.

Comment: Which version of angular 1.x are you using? Also, don't you need to cast the `downgradeComponent()` to `angular.IDirectiveFactory`?

Comment: @camaron nope, I think that is just for show everything else works fine (inputs, outputs). I am using 1.5.1

Comment: @Jackie great, 1.5.1 it's a good start, your directive extends `UpgradeComponent`? And also is inline with the requirements given in the next link? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-component-directives

Comment: @camaron I think you are getting turned around. That link looks like it is for converting angular 1 to angular 2. I am converting angular 2 to angular 1. I am getting a normal component working fine but I am not sure about an attribute directive.

Comment: Nm further down I saw it matched the code on the angular 2 site so yeah it is in line with that.